# Delete previously added hosts form one of the environments

Tags: puppet

I am learning Puppet and trying to remove previously added host overrides from one of the environments I created.

```
class profile::project (
    $key = ''
)
{
    file {'path':
        content => $key,
        ensure  => present,
        group   => 'root',
        mode    => '0644',
        owner   => 'user'
    }
    host { 'storage.googleapis.com':
        name    => 'storage.googleapis.com',
        ensure  => 'present',
        ip      => '000.00.00.00'
    }
    host { 'bigquery.googleapis.com':
        name    => 'bigquery.googleapis.com',
        ensure  => 'present',
        ip      => '000.00.00.00'
    }

    if $::site = 'site' and $::env = 'env'{
        host { 'remove_storage_googleapis_com':
            name    => 'storage.googleapis.com',
            ensure  => 'absent',
            ip => '000.00.00.00'
        }
        host {'remove_bigquery_googleapis_com:
            name    => 'bigquery.googleapis.com',
            ensure  => 'absent',
            ip => '000.00.00.00'
            }
    }
}
```

I receive an error:

> Error: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: Error 500 on SERVER: Server Error: Evaluation Error: Error while evaluating a Resource Statement, Cannot alias Host[remove_storage_googleapis_com] to ["storage.googleapis.com"] at file/path/filename.pp resource ["Host", "storage.googleapis.com"] already declared.

I tried not declaring the resource again with

```
class profile::project (
    $key = ''
)
{
    file {'path':
        content => $key,
        ensure  => present,
        group   => 'root',
        mode    => '0644',
        owner   => 'user'
    }
    if $::site == 'site' and $::env == 'env'{
        $ensure_value == 'absent'
    }
    else {
        $ensure_value == 'present'
    }

    host { 'storage.googleapis.com':
        name    => 'storage.googleapis.com',
        ensure  => $ensure_value,
        ip      => '000.00.00.00'
    }
    host { 'bigquery.googleapis.com':
        name    => 'bigquery.googleapis.com',
        ensure  => $ensure_value,
        ip      => '000.00.00.00'
    }
}
```

but it is giving an error that

> if statement has no effect.  A value was produced and then forgotten (one or more preceding expressions may have the wrong form)

What am I missing here? Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Couldn't you just put the `state=present` entries for `storage.googleapis.com`, etc, into an `else` part of your `if` statement?

Comment: The Puppet code in your question does not throw the indicated error message.

Answer (score 2):

Puppet is a descriptive, not imperative language.
You describe the desired state, not a series of steps for how to achieve it.
Specifically in Puppet

- all resource *titles* of one resource type (e. g. `file`), as well as
- all resource [*name variables*](https://www.Puppet.com/docs/puppet/latest/type#namevars-and-titles) of one resource type (e. g. `path` in the case of `file`)

must [be unique](https://www.Puppet.com/docs/puppet/latest/lang_resources#resource-uniqueness) within the same catalog.
([Exported resources](https://www.Puppet.com/docs/puppet/latest/lang_exported) set further restrictions.)
Although, given that the `if` branch’s condition evaluates to `true`, you have *two* resources with *differing* titles

- `Host['storage.googleapis.com']`, and
- `Host['remove_storage_googleapis_com']`

their *name variables* – in the case of the `host` resource type the `name` attribute – is the *same* value.
This is not permitted as per above rule, two co‑existing resources of the same type with identical name variable values.

> ```
>     if $::site == 'site' and $::env == 'env'{
>         $ensure_value == 'absent'
>     }
>     else {
>         $ensure_value == 'present'
>     }
> ```

Many but not all Puppet language constructs yield a value.
For example a resource declaration also yields a value, an array of resource references to the just declared resources.
Also an `if` statement yields a value, namely the last expression’s value in either branch (or `undef` should no branch apply).

Your problem is that `==` identifies a [comparison](https://www.Puppet.com/docs/puppet/latest/lang_expressions#lang_exp_comparison_operators).
In both cases, since `$ensure_value` is undefined thus resolving to `undef`, the comparison yields the Boolean value `false`, so the *entire* `if` “returns” `false`.
Puppet complains that you do not use this value (`false`).
You meant to use a single equals sign `=` to achieve a [variable assignment](https://www.Puppet.com/docs/puppet/latest/lang_variables#assigning-variables).